# Delphi 7 turn on auto complete

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I'm a new be in Delphi . I use Delphi 7 IDE . How I can turn on the auto complete when I write the code in Delphi 7 IDE ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the menus select Tools | Editor Options. Select the Code Insight page. Make sure that Code completion is checked.

[image]

You can invoke it from the keyboard with CTRL+space.

***Note***: This is all from Delphi 6 but Delphi 7 is pretty much the same as I recall.

Answer (score 2):

It should be default. You can try to force it using ctrl-space. Note that it doesn't always work if your code above contains errors (most notably in the block structure), or in debug mode.